# JScrollbar thumb/knob is not properly painted when it's small

Tags: java, swing

If the view component of a scrollpane is large enough, scrollbar thumb is small and then it is not properly painted on windows L&F.

[image]

It is only an aesthetic problem; the scrollbar functions properly and everything seems to be fine with other L&Fs.

Is there a way to fix that? Maybe somehow to set the minimal width of a thumb?

Comment: no idea how is possible, for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), demonstrated a.m. issue with JScrollBar, short, runnable, compilable, just about JFrame & JScrollPane

Comment: Are you using a custom `ScrollBarUI`?

Comment: @donaldgray noted in a deleted answer that this bug has already been reported: [JDK-8134828](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8134828). Posted on his behalf since he doesn't have enough reputation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me (Java 1.7.0_09, Windows 7):

```
UIManager.put("ScrollBar.minimumThumbSize", new Dimension(32, 32));
```